# I am having trouble lining up a dropdown menu with the correct column grid using bootstrap 3.3.7

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I can not understand why the "list-group panel" does not line up with the second column in this example.  I inserted the entire bootstrap css and js files into the jsfiddle example, was not sure how to reference this code otherwise...

https://jsfiddle.net/oyc9s9gt/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <title>Title</title>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="container-flexible">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1">*1*</div>
          <div class="col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1">*2*</div>
          <div class="col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1">*3*</div>
          <div class="col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1">*4*</div>
          <div class="col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1">*5*</div>
          <div class="col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1">*6*</div>
          <div class="col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1">*7*</div>
          <div class="col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1">*8*</div>
          <div class="col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1">*9*</div>
          <div class="col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1">*10*</div>
          <div class="col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1">*11*</div>
          <div class="col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1">*12*</div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1"></div>
          <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-lg-8">8 Columns</div>
          <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1"></div>
            <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
              <div id="MainMenu">
                <div class="list-group panel">
                  <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-success" data-parent="#MainMenu">Item 1</a>
                  <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-success" data-parent="#MainMenu">Item 2</a>
                  <a href="#demo3" class="list-group-item list-group-item-success" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#MainMenu">Item 3 <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></a>
                  <div class="collapse" id="demo3">
                    <a href="#SubMenu1" class="list-group-item" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#SubMenu1">Subitem 1 <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></a>
                    <div class="collapse list-group-submenu" id="SubMenu1">
                      <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-parent="#SubMenu1">Subitem 1 a</a>
                      <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-parent="#SubMenu1">Subitem 2 b</a>
                      <a href="#SubSubMenu1" class="list-group-item" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#SubSubMenu1">Subitem 3 c <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></a>
                      <div class="collapse list-group-submenu list-group-submenu-1" id="SubSubMenu1">
                        <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-parent="#SubSubMenu1">Sub sub item 1</a>
                        <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-parent="#SubSubMenu1">Sub sub item 2</a>
                      </div>
                      <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-parent="#SubMenu1">Subitem 4 d</a>
                    </div>
                    <a href="javascript:;" class="list-group-item">Subitem 2</a>
                    <a href="javascript:;" class="list-group-item">Subitem 3</a>
                  </div>
                  <a href="#demo4" class="list-group-item list-group-item-success" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#MainMenu">Item 4  <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></a>
                  <div class="collapse" id="demo4">
                    <a href="" class="list-group-item">Subitem 1</a>
                    <a href="" class="list-group-item">Subitem 2</a>
                    <a href="" class="list-group-item">Subitem 3</a>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JQuery code -->
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js">  </script>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified BootStrap Code -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Second Column? Are you referring to the text "8 columns" ? If so then remove the div tags which are above #MainMenu and 8 columns

```
<div class="col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1"></div>
```

And this div which is above #MainMenu

```
<div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
```

This should help. If you meant something else then please explain

Comment: Sorry I did not explain my dilema clearly.  I wanted both the "8 columns" text and the panel to appear on top of each respectively.  Unfortunately, the suggestions mentioned do not seem to create the desired effect.  Maybe you could modify the jsfiddle and show me where my errors are.  I am fairly new to the twitter.bootstrap framework, but not new to general web development.  I assumed the grid design would be very easy to implement, finding it more challenging than I thought it would be....

I just wanted both the text column and panel to line up in the 2nd column.